# iPad displaying strange character when loading a page

Tags: ipad, safari, mobile-safari

Recently my iPad started to display these random characters when I open a website. See the attached image. But when I refresh the page the page loads correctly on safari.[image: Image Error on iPad]

Any idea on how to solve this issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might caused by interruption in loading stream before complete load of the page! So
please try these following steps which might help you to fix this problem:
Go to `Setting > Safari` then *Clear Cookies* & *Clear Cache*